# Mapping data between arrays of different shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mapping

I have an array of data with shape `(256,256,3)` where each value on axis `(0,1)` has the value `[1,0,0], [0,1,0],[0,0,1]` or `[1,1,0]`.

I want to convert this to an array of shape `(256,256,4)` where the values are mapped as follows:

```
[1,0,0] -> [1,0,0,0]
[0,1,0] -> [0,1,0,0]
[0,0,1] -> [0,0,1,0]
[1,1,0] -> [0,0,0,1]
```

I have tried using a loop as follows but it doesnt work.

```
for element in original_array:
    if element == [1, 0, 0]:
        new_array[:,:,0] = 1
    elif element == [0, 1, 0]:
        new_aray[:,:,1] = 1
    elif element == [0, 0, 1]:
        new_array[:,:,2] = 1
    elif element == [1, 1, 0]:
        new_array[:,:,3] = 1
```

I have also tried code like this but im not sure how to correctly implement it:

```
new_array[:,:,0][original_array == [1,0,0]] = 1
new_array[:,:,1][original_array == [0,1,0]] = 1
new_array[:,:,2][original_array == [0,0,1]] = 1
new_array[:,:,3][original_array == [1,1,0]] = 1
```

How do I correctly implement these two methods and what are some alternative methods I can use to accomplish this task?

Comment: Is the fact its a 3 dimensional list relevant to the question? Are't you just replacing the most nested lists? So if you had some code that provided the mapping in your first code block, would that be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's reproduce the problem:

```
a = numpy.array([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1], [1,1,0]])
b = a[numpy.random.randint(0,4,256*256)].reshape(256,256,3)
```

We can insert your original array in an array of zeros with size 4 on the last axis:

```
c = numpy.zeros((b.shape[0], b.shape[1], 4))
c[:,:,:3] = b
```

Then look for the cases where we have 1's at indices 0 and 1, and set the fourth column to 1 where True.

```
c[:,:,3] = b[:,:,:2].all(axis=-1)
```

This uses the equivalence between `True` and 1 (the right side is a boolean array, but we assign it to a float array which gives a value of 1).